# Unable to find some resources on updating the compileSdkVersion to 24

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-resources

I recently tried to update the `compileSdkVersion` to `24`putting the version name in my `app/build.gradle`and also updated the versions for the other libraries. The `buildToolsVersion` that I am using is `23.0.3` which I guess is the latest. When I build my project, it fails giving the error that the build was unable to find some of the resources listed below:

- @drawable/abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha
- @drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha
- @drawable/abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha

This are the internal resources from provided by the SDK and I have been using them for quite some time now. I don't know why is it failing now. Any ideas?

Comment: try File ->Invalidate Caches\Restart ->Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This are the internal resources from provided by the SDK

This is your issue.
These resources are private to the support lib or framework and you can't rely on them being there.
So now the compiler does not let you access them.

You can easily get the corresponding icons here : https://design.google.com/icons/

and import them in your project.

Comment: thanks a lot.. never thought about that and probably that is why in the new compiled SDK version, even if we have have these internal resources, the build fails if we use them.